# Create Dynamic Date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a dynamic date in mysql. I have written it for mssql but having troubles with mysql.

```
createdate(getyear(currentdate()) ,10,01)
```

I have tried STR_TO_Date() but i can't make the year dynamic. Any thoughts ?

Comment: What's the input and what's the output you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a MySQL-only solution to getting the current year,

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM NOW());
```

should do what you want.
Or for the whole date,

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-10-01');
```

Comment: When running the query for the whole date i get BLOB in the as a result. Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 0):

That worked:
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(10,31,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURDATE())), '%m%d%Y') ;